# Set the outline level "+" sign on the left side

Tags: c#, excel

> AAA       |       1111
>  AAA        |       2222     
> AAA        |       3333
>  BBB        |       1111
>   BBB       |       2222

I want to group the first column, and set the outline level on the left side.
Below are the codes that i use to group the first column with 'AAA' value

```
MyExcel.Range rr1 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
MyExcel.Range rr2 = xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1];
MyExcel.Range rrangeGroup = (MyExcel.Range)xlWorkSheet.get_Range(rr1, rr2);
rrangeGroup.Group();

xlWorkSheet.Outline.SummaryColumn = MyExcel.XlSummaryColumn.xlSummaryOnLeft;
```

but when i use the code to set the outline level on the left side, i've encountered an error "**Unable to set the SummaryColumn property of the Outline class**"

Can someone help me on these issue

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: my expected output is to display the outline level on the left side of the excel, but in the code **xlWorkSheet.Outline.SummaryColumn = MyExcel.XlSummaryColumn.xlSummaryOnLeft;** in getting an error **"Unable to set the SummaryColumn property of the Outline class"**

Comment: i've found the solution of this issue

i've replace
 **rrangeGroup.Group();**
to
 **rrange.Rows.Group();**

this will automatically display this outline level sign "+" on the left side